# Initializing objects in a for loop in java?

Tags: java, object, initialization

Assuming `Sports`, `School`, `Home` are classes in Java.
with `Home` having a method e.g.

```
void add(Sports t1, School t2);
```

Here is what i want to do:

```
Sports s1 = new Sports("value1");
School t2 = new School("value1");
Home h = new Home();
h.add(s1,t2);
```

Now the problem is, i want to repeat these steps too many times. with `h` remaining the same. So that `h.add()` is called multiple times with different objects as parameters with values coming from outside using forloop.
can someone show me how can i initialize these objects and call
the add method in e,g a for loop with different object names in
each iteration?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. What's varying on each iteration of the loop? Note that *variable* names are very different from *object* names (objects don't have names).

Comment: Technically, they do have names (or at least a system identity, which is a name in a particular sense). You hardly ever want to know them though, especially since you can't look them up by name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is where you will want to use arrays (or lists).

Example:

```
Home h = new Home();
Sports[] sports = new Sports[10];
School[] schools = new School[10];
for (int i =0; i< sports.length; i++) {
    h.add(sports[i], schools[i]);
}
```

In the above example you will need a way to initialize the contents of the `sports` and `schools` arrays.

Perhaps this slight variation of above is what you need:

```
Home h = new Home();
String[] sports = // existing array of sport names
String[] schools = // array of school names
for (int i =0; i< sports.length; i++) {
    h.add(new Sports(sports[i]), new School(schools[i]));
}
```

Here we use arrays of school and sport names to create all of the objects that get added to `Home`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create many `Home` objects, each of which have a `Sports` and a `School` object, then you'll want to use an [array](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) or a [collection class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) to store those objects. Let's assume you're using an array to store the `Home` objects, then it could look something like this:

```
// Array to store 10 Home objects
Home[] homes = new Home[10];

// Initialize each object in the array
for (int i = 0; i < homes.length; ++i) {
    homes[i] = new Home();

    // Create a Sports and a School object
    Sports sports = new Sports();
    School school = new School();

    // Add those to the i'th Home object
    homes[i].add(sports, school);
}
```

*edit* Or, do you want to create just one `Home` object and add multiple `Sports` and `Schools` object to it? Then it's even simpler:

```
Home home = new Home();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    // Create a Sports and a School object
    Sports sports = new Sports();
    School school = new School();

    home.add(sports, school);
}
```

Comment: He clarified that `Home` stays constant in his problem.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of Sports and School

```
Home h = new Home();
int count = 10;
Sports[] sports = new Sports[count];
School[] school = new School[count];
for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
sports[i] = new Sports();
school[i] = new School();
h.add(sports[i],school[i]);
}
```

Comment: it depends. in the code i gave you.. After the for loop, you will still have the 10 schools and sports.. If you dont want them any more then you only need a for loop like jjnguy said

Answer (score 1):

Init an array of the required names and then use it to seed the `Home` instance.

```
Home h = new Home(); 
String[] names = new String[5]; 

// populate names here
// ...
// now populate Home
for (String name : names)
{     
    h.add(new Sports(name), new School(name));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but don't you think i will be using two loops when the task can be accomplished in just one loop.

Comment: If you want different values in the inputs to `h.add` then you need more logic than provided so far.  If each `h.add` uses the same `Sports` and `School` name, then you are correct that only one loop is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
Home h = new Home();
while (CONDITION) {
   Sports t1 = new Sports();
   School s1 = new School();
   h.add(t1, s1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, Do you think this is also a correct approach:

```
Sports s1;
School t2;
Home h = new Home();

for(int i=0; i<mysize; i++){
   s1 = new Sports("value");  //so i will change it as per the logic
   t2 = new School("value");
   h.add(s1, t2);
}
```

I am not sure though if this the right approach.

Comment: `value` should be a variable that's given a value based on some condition of the for loop, rather than a String that says "value", but yes that should work.

Comment: @Anthony yes you are right. Actually these values will be coming in from JDBC connection as strings whcih i will add to those objects in this loop